# Shell script port scanner

Tags: shell, port-scanning

I would like to scan multiple ports in multiple hosts. I used this script but it takes long time to show the result.

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=(
"server1"
"server2"
)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
        echo "=========================================="
        echo "Scanning $host"
        echo "=========================================="
            for port in {21,22,80}
            do
            echo "" > /dev/tcp/$host/$port && echo "Port $port is open"
    done 2>/dev/null
done
```

Some people suggested to use `telnet` or `NetCat` instead but i prefer to do it without installing any new packages. So, are there any ways to speed it up by multithreading or other way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GNU Parallel to run all the checks in parallel. I am not the best at using it, and @OleTange (the author) normally has to correct me but I keep trying. So, let's try your case, by building up to it slowly:

```
parallel echo {1} {2} ::: 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.8 ::: 21 22 80

192.168.0.8 22
192.168.0.8 80
192.168.0.8 21
192.168.0.1 80
192.168.0.1 22
192.168.0.1 21
```

looks kind of hopeful to me. Then I add in `-k` to keep the results in order, and I supply a function that takes those IP addresses and ports as arguments:

```
parallel -k 'echo "" > /dev/tcp/{1}/{2} && echo {1}:{2} is open' ::: 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.8 ::: 21 22 80 2>/dev/null
192.168.0.1:80 is open
192.168.0.8:21 is open
192.168.0.8:22 is open
192.168.0.8:80 is open
```

This will run 8 jobs in parallel if your CPU has 8 cores, however `echo` is not very resource intensive so you can probably run 32 in parallel, so add `-j 32` after the `-k`.

If you wanted to stick closer to your own script, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
hosts=(
"192.168.0.1"
"192.168.0.8"
)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
   for port in {21,22,80}
   do
      echo "(echo > /dev/tcp/$host/$port) 2>/dev/null && echo Host:$host Port:$port is open"
   done
done | parallel -k -j 32
```

Basically, instead of running your commands, I am just sending them to the `stdin` of `parallel` so it can do its magic with them.

Answer (score 1):

You could run all three pokes in the background, then wait for them all to finish, and probably slash the running time to 1/3.

```
for port in 21 22 80; do
    echo "" > /dev/tcp/$host/$port 2>/dev/null &
    pid[$port]=$!
done
for port in 21 22 80; do
    wait $pid[$port] && echo "Port $port" is open"
done
```

You could add parallelism by running multiple hosts in the background, too, but that should be an obvious extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
function alarm {
  local timeout=$1; shift;
  # execute command, store PID
  bash -c "$@" &
  local pid=$!
  # sleep for $timeout seconds, then attempt to kill PID
  {
    sleep "$timeout"
    kill $pid 2> /dev/null
  } &
  wait $pid 2> /dev/null 
  return $?
}
function scan {
  if [[ -z $1 || -z $2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: ./scanner <host> <port, ports, or port-range>"
    echo "Example: ./scanner google.com 79-81"
    return
  fi

  local host=$1
  local ports=()
  # store user-provided ports in array
  case $2 in
    *-*)
      IFS=- read start end <<< "$2"
      for ((port=start; port <= end; port++)); do
        ports+=($port)
      done
      ;;
    *,*)
      IFS=, read -ra ports <<< "$2"
      ;;
    *)
      ports+=($2)
      ;;
  esac

  # attempt to write to each port, print open if successful, closed if not
  for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
    alarm 1 "echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$port" &&
      echo "$port/tcp open" ||
      echo "$port/tcp closed"
  done
}
scan $1 $2
```